# How to check if 2 PictureBox images have similar names

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I'm trying to check if 2 pictureboxes from an array of pictureboxes contain similar image names.Any help is appreciated here's some part's of my code

```
string[] ImgLocation = Directory.GetFiles("Assets\\Cards", "*.png",
                                          SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
Image[] Deck = new Image[52];
PictureBox[] Holder = new PictureBox[52];
Deck[i] = Image.FromFile(ImgLocation[i]);
Holder[i] = new PictureBox();
Holder[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
Holder[i].Height = 130;
Holder[i].Width = 80;
this.Controls.Add(Holder[i]);
Holder[i].Name = "pb" + i.ToString();
Holder[i].Image = Deck[i];
```

Comment: 52 picture boxes is a _lot_ of picture boxes.

Comment: I need 52 for a reason and need to check only few of them at a time

Comment: Define "similar image names"

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You might store this information in one of the specific properties of the `PictureBox` control (e.g., `ImageLocation`); or plainly use `Tag` (the box where you can store anything). Once you have all the file names (even whole paths) in place, you might do quite a few things to determine which ones are similar enough.

Comment: you have two different problems here: link a file name to a picture box, (see @varocarbas comment) and find "similar name", whatever this means. split your problem in two smaller problem: it probabily will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: It's a poker app so the name of the images are for example 2_of_spades 2_of_hearts and so on.. i'm currently trying to convert Deck and Holder arrays to byte array but i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: So you actually have full control of the names. Now: Where is the problem??? Look into the usual string functions: substring indexof etc..!

Comment: I dont know how to check the picturebox.image.name

Answer (score 0):

Have you concidered using Lists (LINQ) which have better comparing capabilities ?

Comment: it wont help me i tried this already i just need to get the picturebox.backgroundimage.name